# How to access numpy array with a set of indices stored in another numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array which stores a set of indices I need to access another numpy array.

I tried to use a `for` loop but it doesn't work as I expected.

The situation is like this:

```
>>> a
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
>>> c
array([[0, 0],
       [0, 1]])
>>> a[c[0]]
array([[1, 2],
       [1, 2]])
>>> a[0,0]         # the result I want
1
```

Above is a simplified version of my actual code, where the `c` array is much  larger so I have to use a `for` loop to get every index.

Comment: Seems very relevant - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41802319

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert it to a `tuple`:

```
>>> a[tuple(c[0])]
1
```

Because `list` and `array` indices trigger [advanced indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). `tuple`s are (mostly) basic slicing.

Answer (score 1):

Index `a` with columns of `c` by passing the first column as row's index and second one as column index:

```
In [23]: a[c[:,0], c[:,1]]
Out[23]: array([1, 2])
```