# Numpy array as indices in multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

This seems totally simple. In a way it's as if I just need to get rid of some square brackets. I want to use an array to be the indices of a multidimensional array. I must be a total dummy. Here's my minimal example:

```
import numpy as np

## I know this is a dumb way to initialize.
state = np.array([[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]],[[10,11,12],[13,14,15],[16,17,18]]])
print('state\n',state)
a = np.array([0,0,0])
print('a',a)

## I want to use a as the indices of state a la:
print('state[a]\n',state[a])

## If I could just get rid of the brackets I'd be fine:
print('state[0,0,0]\n',state[0,0,0])

## This gets me what I want, but it is UGLY in non-minimal case:
print('state[a[0],a[1],a[2]]\n',state[a[0],a[1],a[2]])
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

just convert your index array to tuple

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/15065236)

Comment: @Lundin Doesn't it? Ok, there was a confusing typo ('list' instead of 'array'), but other than that? Actually, why not have a look at the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41951183/7207392) to the duplicate?

Comment: The problem with this answer, unlike the accepted one in the linked duplicate, is that you provide no explanation about why or how this solves the problem. In its current form, this would have been better off as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Lundin Ok, fair  enough. What do you suggest?

Comment: Because the answer was so brief, it automatically ended up in the low quality review queue, which is how I got here. Since the question is now closed as a duplicate, I wouldn't bother fixing the answer, leave it as it is. It may or may not get deleted through reviewer consensus.